# Magento Banners frequently loose the link to the related promotion

Tags: magento

We have noticed that the shopping cart banners seem to frequently loose the link to the related promotion without anyone making this change within admin. Is there a setting that only allows a certain number of customers to see this banner and then it would be removed? I can’t think of another reason it might just drop the link. It isn’t dropping all the links, and it has usually been the lower value ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup cron.php to be accessed in a cronjob. Verify by hitting cron.php manually and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Cron.php is already setup and working fine , but the issue is still there.